# Kotlin init block didn't execute

Tags: android, kotlin, android-seekbar

I created a custom SeekBar which extends `android.widget.Seekbar`:

```
data class Range(val min: Int, val max: Int, private val defaultIncrement: Int) {
    val increment = if ((max - min) < defaultIncrement) 1 else defaultIncrement
}

internal fun Range.toSeekbarMaximum(): Int = (max - min) / increment

class RangeSeekBar: SeekBar {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    init {
        range = Range(0, 100, 1)
    }

    var range: Range
        set(value) {
            max = value.toSeekbarMaximum()
        }

    override fun setProgress(progress: Int) = super.setProgress((progress - range.min) / range.increment)

    override fun getProgress(): Int = range.min + super.getProgress() * range.increment
}
```

I got an NPE when I run the codes, `constructor` executed firstly, then goes to `setProgress`, it crashed because `range` is null. The `init` block didn't execute after `constructor`, anything wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a property and initializing that property in an init block like how you have it is the same as initializing the property upon declaration. The init block is only executed when the primary constructor is called. You have the default primary constructor (an empty constructor) and custom secondary constructors. If you want that to be executed in the init block, you'll have to call the primary constructor. If you want range to be init'd upon construction every time, just init it upon declaration and get rid of the init block.

```
var range: Range = Range(0, 100, 1)
    set(value){
        max = value.toSeekbarMaximum()
        field = value
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're overriding the setter of `range` and not setting its backing field to the new values. This should fix it:

```
var range: Range
    set(value) {
        field = value
        max = value.toSeekbarMaximum()
    }
```